# how to install system ruby after installing rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed rvm, with ruby 1.8.7, ruby1.9.2 and ruby1.9.3,

when i try,

```
>sudo gem install passenger
sudo: gem: command not found

>sudo ruby -v
sudo: ruby: command not found

>rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p371 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

>sudo su
># ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

I realized that there is no default ruby in my system.
my aim is to install passenger to configure it with apache in localhost to enable HTTPS.
How can i proceed from my current setup

Comment: The whole point of rvm is that you don't need sudo rights to install gems anymore.

Comment: thanks squiguy, i installed passenger without sudo. it works like a charm!

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, using rvm is nice since you can install things and break them without worrying about your system's binaries. :) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have administrative (sudo) rights, then install system wide Ruby.

You would issue the command `rvm use system`

If it is installed, then you will be able to run `ruby -v` to see if there is a Ruby install (and if you installed RVM you likely have at least Ruby 1.8 installed, as it is a requirement for certain versions of Ruby with RVM.

Then proceed to install Ruby as per your package manager.